# What are ways to run a MySQL query in PHP and output the result to an array in less space?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting really tired of writing:

```
$rows = array();
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `field`='".$information."'");
while($row = $result){
    $rows[] = $row;
}
```

I tried a function, but it was kinda of messy feeling changing the input to field inputs. I thought maybe this or something similar would help:

```
$rows = array(); 
while($row = ($db->query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `field`='".$information."'"))->fetch_assoc()){
    $rows[] = $row;
}
```

but I get `unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR`. I'm still on the line about using a function. Maybe there's a more efficient way of writing one. This is how I tried writing a function:

```
$array = SELECT ($db,$toSelect,$table,$where);
```

It still seems cumbersome, however. I would like something like $array = $db->("MYSQL");

Comment: which PHP version you have ?

Comment: Yes below PHP 5.4 this way of object usage is not supported I suppose $res = ($obj->query())->somefunction() you need to split that into 2 lines..

Comment: Wow, great answer. I didn't know that. That's a good feature.

Answer (score 1):

- The simplest solution is to write a function, which expects a database handle and a string query parameter, and returns all the rows.

  `$rows = fetch_all($db, "SELECT ...");`
- A bit more advanced is to write your own database class which wraps the database handle and adds such functionality.

  `$rows = $mydb->fetch_all("SELECT ...");`
- If you don't want to reinvent the wheel, simply use an existing ORM / PHP database library which does all this (and more) for you.

  `$db
      ->select('*')
      ->from('table')
      ->where('field', $information);`

Note: http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php - the third solution automatically solves this problem.

Comment: Is there a way to copy the mysqli class? I think that's what the database object is of.

Comment: practically you probably need 5-10 functions from there, so it's not a big deal.

Comment: I was trying to figure out how to do the second one, although inputting a string does make the regular function nicer.

Comment: this is not DB related, but should be enough to get you started: http://wshell.wordpress.com/2009/10/12/encapsulation-in-php/

Comment: I see. Is there a way to assign an object's function to a variable? How do you set the classes default function? Like in $db->()?